# Can r.m One-way ANOVA be used to compare differences between groups, if those groups are made up of median values?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics, median, treatment-effect

Essentially, I'm trying to see whether a drug affects a latency measure. I have $n=10$ mice, each with $15$ individual latency recordings (in seconds) per drug dose (repeated measures design). Most of these sets of data are positively skewed, so taking the median value (as opposed to the mean) is preferable.

So now I have the median latency for each mouse at each drug dose, my question is: can I still use a repeated measures one-way ANOVA to compare between the drug doses? Usually, I am comparing mean values, not median values, so I'm a little unsure.

Comment: What about taking the log of latency, and then proceeding with the usual analysis?

Comment: My concern with taking the log is that no other research paper in my area seems to do this, and being able to see and compare the actual latency (in seconds) is very important to my research question @dipetkov

Comment: I understand the reluctance to do something that's not done in your field. On the other hand, taking the log of a duration variable (positive, skewed, with a large range) is often done. I would prefer to do that and fit a regression to all the data, without averaging first; even if the model is for log(Y), I can get inference on the original scale by back-transforming.

Comment: If you prefer to work with the median instead, you can look into quantile regression.

Answer (score 1):

##### Quantile Approach

As dipetkov rightfully noted, quantile regression (QR) is a useful approach if you want to use medians or quantiles to approximate relationships in the data. Below are some references that I find very useful, though the full book by Koenker can be a bit more mathematically involved than the other references. I particularly like Koenker & Hallock, 2001, as it provides a pretty gentle introduction to the topic. You can model in the time directly into the regression.

Since you are dealing with 15 repeated measures of these latencies, you will have to account for the non-independence of errors in the model (which I assume is why you wanted to use an RM ANOVA). I'm not sure if normal quantile regression software/functions allow for this in a sophisticated way, but I do know that the `qgam` function in R, which can model both linear and nonlinear quantile regressions, allows you to supply random effects into the model, which your measurement period can be used as to account for non-independence. I have linked some reading material on that too, though some understanding of GAMs may be necessary to fully appreciate what is said there. Modeling it in R would look something like this:

```
fit <- qgam(RT ~ dose + s(period, bs = "re), qu = .50, data = data)
```

This models dose as a linear effect and accounts for the repeated measures by modeling period as a random effect. The `qu = .50` models the median.

##### LMER Approach

However there is one caveat I would like to add. You mentioned you are using latencies and they are positively skewed. This seems to resemble what I know about human latencies, which typically take on an inverse Gaussian distribution (which means it his *highly* skewed). You could instead make this *a lot* simpler by doing a transformation of the data that normalizes reaction times and then run a normal linear mixed model on it:

$$
\text{invRT} = \frac{-1000}{\text{RT}}
$$

This transformation is typically performed on reaction time/latencies by milliseconds, so you may need to adapt the formula to account for the number of seconds mice take to respond (I'm guessing in tens or hundreds of seconds instead of 1000s of milliseconds). Doing so allows you to simply fit a linear regression with the variables you want, with the caveat that you add in measurement period as a random effect. The paper by Brysbaert and Stevens discusses how one typically does this in R using the `lme4` package's `lmer` function, though reading Bates et al., 2015 may help with familiarizing yourself with mixed models.

If for some reason your data doesn't normalize with the above transformation but its clear your data resembles an inverse Gaussian distribution, you can also directly model that as a generalized linear mixed model using the same `lme4` package's `glmer` function, though you will need the `invgauss` package to model that distribution into `glmer`.

##### References

- Bates, D., Mächler, M., Bolker, B., & Walker, S. (2015). Fitting linear mixed-effects models using lme4. Journal of Statistical Software, 67(1). https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v067.i01
- Brysbaert, M., & Stevens, M. (2018). Power analysis and effect size in mixed effects models: A tutorial. Journal of Cognition, 1(1), 9. https://doi.org/10.5334/joc.10
- Fasiolo, M., Wood, S. N., Zaffran, M., Nedellec, R., & Goude, Y. (2021). Qgam: Bayesian nonparametric quantile regression modeling in R. Journal of Statistical Software, 100(9). https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v100.i09
- Koenker, R. (2005). Quantile regression. Cambridge University Press.
- Koenker, R., & Hallock, K. F. (2001). Quantile regression. Journal of Economic Perspectives, 15(4), 143–156. https://doi.org/10.1257/jep.15.4.143
- Waldmann, E. (2018). Quantile regression: A short story on how and why. Statistical Modelling, 18(3–4), 203–218. https://doi.org/10.1177/1471082X18759142
- Wenz, S. E. (2019). What quantile regression does and doesn’t do: A commentary on Petscher and Logan (2014). Child Development, 90(4), 1442–1452. https://doi.org/10.1111/cdev.13141